# Converting VDI (VirtualBox) image to physical (bootable) partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, virtualbox, windows-10

Let be start by giving you some background. I'm currently using Ubuntu as my OS, but I also recently installed Windows 10 using VirtualBox. I needed Windows to create WindowsService in C#. So far so good. Unfortunately my laptop have huge trouble running Windows in VM and I'd like to move that installed Windows 10 to a partition on my hard drive (I have 100GB~ on one of my partitions that I no longer use).

What I would like to achieve is the ability to dual-boot into that Windows 10 from Grub.

The first question is - is that even possible?
The second question is - what do I do to make it work?